# Different ways for solving Race condition in distributed environment in Rest Services in java

Tags: java, rest, concurrency, distributed-computing

Here is a description of a problem that I am facing right now

1. I want to give user some promotion based on whether he has done a transaction in which he has been given a promotional discount
2. Promotional discount is some percent off on the transaction
3. So the condition is, before processing transactions, it will be checked whether he as done a transaction using a promotion or not, and based on that amount will be calculated.

Problem is if two request comes at the same time and reads that a transaction has not been done, and on both the transaction promotion is applied.

Found a solution, https://dzone.com/articles/synchronized-by-the-value-of-the-object-in-java, but not valid for distributed environment.

**What are can be different ways to solve such a program. Was just very curious on this problem >**

Comment: Is your code talking to a DBMS? I'm not an expert, but if there's a DBMS, then I would expect your "transactions" to be implemented as actual [DBMS transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). OTOH, if there is _not_ a DBMS, then maybe you should say more about what "distributed" means for your application.

Comment: Yes it is DBMS, but its not what you understood. My check is that if there is an existing entry in my db then i don't have to apply promo, and if there isn't then i will have to apply promo. Now if two different request come to process a transaction at the same time,  when there is no entry in my db, then what should i do in that case

Comment: Are you working with a DBMS that supports transaction isolation levels (most rdbms engines will do)? Or is this a nosql (like mongodb) with different transactional properties? The solution is different for each case.

Comment: @BurakSerdar - Hi, I am using mysql as backend database

Comment: Did you try to implement optimistic locking? Or if it's just two concurrent insert operations then you might have some unique identity to differentiate transactions. if there are you can mark that column as unique. So the second insert with same value will be rejected

Comment: @Joshgun Records are transactions initiated by user, so it will have different transaction ids, plus promotions does not have any coupon so I don't have anything unique between two transaction. the check is that if user has an existing txn, then he should not get promo.

Comment: But you say when concurrent inserts are made I can see two same entries. How do you know that they are two same transactions? How you differentiate two same transactions and two other transactions belong to different users?

Comment: @Joshgun-  No If you carefully read above, the condition is, before processing transactions, it will be checked whether he as done a transaction using a promotion or not, and based on that amount will be calculated. And is if two different ttxn come at the same time, and there is no exiting txn in db, so promo can be applied to both txns.

Comment: One way you can do this is this: you can search to see if there is a record that entitles a promotion. If there is, you can "select for update" that record, and see if the promotion is already used. If not, apply the promotion and commit. Otherwise do not apply the promotion and commit. You have to do all these in a single transaction. Since the record for the promotion is locked, any other transaction trying to lock that record will fail.

Comment: @BurakSerdar the thing is, Its a user transaction and it has to be unique, so can't think of an update. Plus i don't want to fail transaction, i just want user to stop, if one transaction is in process, or pause it, just like how it happens in bank to check and deduct balance

Comment: I didn't say update, I said "select for update", so it locks the row. I didn't say transaction would fail, it would commit. If two transactions come at the same time for the user, one should wait while the other is keeping the lock.

Comment: @BurakSerdar - Thanks for the answer. It can work well in some cases. But in case, First I am checking, whether any txn exists, then I am making a rest API call, after that based on its response, I will insert txn status as success. There can be 1 or 2 seconds gap here

Comment: You need to work in two phases then: phase1: check if user is entitled to a promotion using "select for update", and commit the transaction to release the lock. The you can make your rest API call, and based on the result, again check for promotion using "select for update".

Comment: @BurakSerdar - Yeah that will work. Thanks
Just out of interest what if its a NOSQL database?? How to resolved this problem then

Comment: Mongodb is an example for a nosql database. As the name implies, they don't use SQL for querying. They provide different transactional capabilities. If the DB doesn't support transactions, it usually offers document-level atomic updates. Exact implementation of this kind of logic depends on the db and how it is deployed. It may not be possible under some scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distributed environments require distributed locks. And there are a lot of options from here, we have used `zookeeper` for this, some other team of mine used `redis`. I also know (theoretically) that `hazelcast` has such a principle also; I bet there are many more.

There are some things you need to consider in a distributed environment that slightly complicate things. What if the service that "provides" the locking mechanism dies, what if the client that acquired a lock never releases it (it might die or block internally forever), etc. There are fault tolerant policies for the first and there are mechanisms for the second (a timeout for release or an "auto-disconnect" of the lock).

Some time ago I worked for a company that did this "by hand" against a MSSQL database. What they did (I was only a consumer of that service), is create a java-agent that would instrument byte-code and, at some points of execution would connect to a database and try to "CAS" (compare-and-swap) a certain row in a table. I don't know the faith of that project now, but I still love the idea to this day.

Bottom line is that there are *many* options, really. It highly depends on your infrastructure and team that you are involved in.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, also can you please elaborate on the solution that you mentioned at last of your answer, it looks something interesting, but didn't quite get it

Comment: @gaurav9620 well you need to understand a few things here, like what is a java agent, how can it instrument code ( add some code to the initial bytecode that was generated from your classes )... When that makes sense the rest is easy: that injected code used to go to a database ( simplified explanation ) and try to insert `1` into a certain field if it was `0` ( `1` meaning that the lock is taken, `0` meaning it is free ). If it did that - current thread is the owner, if it could not it would wait a little and retry. This is very much like CAS works ( or a spin lock ), at least logically.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways this can be achieved. Accessing the table using serializable transaction isolation level is one way. However, since you mentioned the process involves potentially long running external calls as well, then you can do a two-phase approach like this:

- Start a transaction
- Use "select for update" to search and lock the record that entitles the user with a promotion.
- Check if the promotion is used already. If yes, commit the transaction, promotion is not available. If no, commit the transaction. Promotion is available.
- Do your external calls
- Start a transaction and do the promotion check again, with "select for update", but this time, insert the record for using the promotion as well

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's a good idea, but my use case would be to reject the transaction if one is already under process, and show user the message, that one transaction is under process and to try once its status is updated. Moreover, is there a solution without using a database-level transaction management system?

Comment: Your use of transaction is really confusing. When you say "reject the transaction" are you talking about db transaction or user transaction? What I outlined would allow only one request to succeed and any other concurrent requests to fail. The first phase checks if promotion is available. The second phase again checks if it is available and uses it. Only one concurrent request will be able to use a promotion, all others will fail.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, by transaction I meant user transaction, I want to stop the user from transacting if one transaction on which promotion is to applied is already in place. Got your point. So is there any way to solve this problem apart from using select for update or in general without using database-level handling?

Comment: If you have multiple hosts talking to the db you have to use either the db transactions or another method to coordinate the transactions. If there is only one host you can do without db transactions.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple hosts. That is what I was asking, what other coordinating methods can be used?

Comment: I've seen Zookeper used for similar scenarios. Redis can be used. The bottom line is that they allow a distributed synchronization mechanism that can also be achieved by using the database itself without introducing another component to the infrastructure.

Comment: @Burak Serdar What if the database has multiple write replicas? Will the transaction isolation levels of one write replica guarantee the data won't be modified in another write replica?